# Oracle SQL run batch

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, oracle10g, procedure

So what we trying to do is create a procedure that execute a batch file.

We been messing around with job instruction, but it seems like it doesn't work properly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE launch_bat AS
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('Export_Case_Job',
                             job_action            => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',
                              number_of_arguments   => 3,
                              job_type              => 'executable',
                              enabled               => FALSE);

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('Export_Case_Job', 1, '/q');

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('Export_Case_Job', 2, '/c');

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('Export_Case_Job', 3, 'C:\scripts\helloFolder.bat');

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('Export_Case_Job');
END;
/


call launch_bat;
```

It says that it compiled but we don't see any result in our folder. We also tried to give a file name in call.

We have Oracle 10.2 so we can't use `exec xp_cmdshell`.

Why procedure ? When we get new income data, we will execute a trigger with procedure that will go for a batch file, this batch file will create a certain information inside our folders as a test purporse.

The main focus is that oracle sql execute a batch file.

Batch content

```
ECHO OFF
mkdir C:\scripts\folder
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So where is the batch file content? this is just the plsql code..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard For test purporse, for now it only will create folders.`ECHO OFF
mkdir C:\scripts\folder`

Comment: I still need to at least see the content to see complete picture before I can answer

Comment: Thanks for the change. What is the reason you call cmd, when you can just schedule the batch file directly?

Comment: The batch file needs to exist on the Oracle server, not on your local computer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm executing this from Oracle server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compare your example with the one from the docs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#CHDJHBAH:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
   job_name             => 'MKDIR_JOB',
   job_type             => 'EXECUTABLE',
   number_of_arguments  => 3,
   job_action           => '\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
   auto_drop            => FALSE,
   credential_name      => 'TESTCRED');

 DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('mkdir_job',1,'/c');
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('mkdir_job',2,'mkdir');
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('mkdir_job',3,'\temp\extjob_test_dir');
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('MKDIR_JOB');
END;
/
```

1. EXECUTABLE vs. executable
2. \windows\system32\cmd.exe vs C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE

So I would expect that you have to write job_type in upper case. Probably job_action lower case, but I'm not sure there.

If the error is somewhere else you have to check:

```
*_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG
*_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
```

Where I could find sufficiant information to migrate the example from the docs to linux with mkdir.

Comment: Hello, your answer is correct. I keep having trouble with other stuff, but this one makes a half way work. Thanks.